# What dialects change ます into やす?

Tags: dialects

What dialects change ます into やす, as in these examples:

> - 「何が**出やした**か…？見ておくんなせェ」
> - 「そう**決めやした**ね…？」
> - 「ならあちらさんの勝ちだ…今夜は逮捕**しやせん**」

It appears to be Edo dialect.  Is that correct?

Comment: It'd be good if someone could confirm this, but it appears to be Edo dialect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, one can call it Edo dialect and all of your examples look Edo/Tokyo as well.  Today, 「やす」 is no longer used by many in real life around Tokyo.  It is more "known" as the honorific sentence-ender in the underworld in fiction.

I would need to point out, though, that the auxiliary verb 「やす」 was originally a Kansai phenomenon.  It is still used in Kyoto in polite imperatives.